# Prediction for all samples in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, prediction

I am doing prediction in `R` using

```
model<- train(Label~., data = training, trControl=train_control, method="rf")
Predict_RF <-predict(model, newdata = testing)
```

How can I do the prediction for all samples? I mean, if I want to do the prediction not only for the test set (doing it even for the samples inside the training set), how I can do that?

Appreciate.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with a reproducible [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for some great advice.)

Comment: `predict(model, newdata = testing)` followed by `predict(model, newdata = training)`. Sometimes life is easy when kept simple and seperate. Or if you have a full dataset, lets call it `df`, then `predict(model, newdata = df)`.